# Server Log Showing Many 'Unhandled Exceptions' From URL with &hash=

Tags: asp.net, url, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, unhandled-exception

I've noticed a large increase in the number of events logged daily that have *&hash=* in the URL. The requested URL is the same every time but the number that follows the *&hash=* is always different.

I have no idea what the purpose of the *&hash=* parameter is, so I'm unsure if these attempts are malicious or something else. Can anyone provide insight as to what is being attempted with the requested URL? I have copied in one from a recent log below.

```
https://www.movinglabor.com:443/moving-services/moving-labor/move-furniture/&du=https:/www.movinglabor.com/moving-services/moving-labor/move.../&hash=AFD3C9508211E3F234B4A265B3EF7E3F
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable without more information. What server are you running? What's logging the errors? Do you get any indication what the exception is?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2. I am seeing the errors in Windows Event Viewer for ASP.NET events. The exception info provided by the log is below.

Comment: Exception information: 
    Exception type: HttpException 
    Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 1):

I have been seeing the same thing in IIS on Windows Server 2012 R2.  They were mostly HEAD requests.  I did see a few other more obvious attack attempts from the same ip address so I'm assuming the du/hash thing is also intended to be malicious.

Here's an example of another attempt which also tries some url encoding to bypass filters:

```
part_id=D8DD67F9S8DF79S8D7F9D9D%5C&du=https://www.examplesite.com/page..asp%5C?part...%5C&hash=DA54E35B7D77F7137E|-|0|404_Not_Found
```

So you may want to look through your IIS logs to see if they are trying other things. 
In the end I simply created a blocking rule for it using the [Url Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) extension for IIS.